# How can I display data pulled from Firebase in React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am working on a website and learning React and Firebase. I am able to pull data from Firebase and display it on the page using a map and returning a div for each  element however I would like all the information pulled to be displayed in a component I created for them to have consistent styling with the rest of the page.

When trying to cycle through the `posts` array, I get an error saying `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` however when I `console.log` the array all the objects are displayed correctly. Is there a way to access the array by index or am I going about this the wrong way?

Here is the MRE:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { TrendBar, TrendCard } from '../components'
import { db } from '../firebase'
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore'

const Home = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'posts');

    useEffect(() => {
        const getPosts = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(collectionRef)
            setPosts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
        }
        getPosts()
    }, [])

    return (

        <>
        {/* displays all elements of the db on the page  */}
        {posts.map((post) => {
            return <div>
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            </div>
        })}

        {/* Would like to display the elements like this */}
            <TrendBar
                firstTrend={
                    <TrendCard
                        id={posts[0].id}
                        image={posts[0].image}
                        imageAlt={posts[0].imageAlt}
                        title={posts[0].title}
                        tags={posts[0].tags}
                    />
                  }
                secondTrend={
                    <TrendCard
                        id={posts[1].id}
                        image={posts[1].image}
                        imageAlt={posts[1].imageAlt}
                        title={posts[1].title}
                        tags={posts[1].tags}
                    />
                 }
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the array.length !== 0 before drawing it.
There are several ways how you can check it, the simplest one is that:

```
posts.length && posts.map((post) => {
                return <div>
                    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                </div>
            })}

posts?.map((post) => {
            return <div>
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            </div>
        })}
```

Also, to prevent errors in the future, we have the new syntax:

```
<TrendBar
            firstTrend={
                <TrendCard
                    **id={posts?.[0].id}**
                    image={posts[0].image}
                    imageAlt={posts[0].imageAlt}
                    title={posts[0].title}
                    tags={posts[0].tags}
                />
```

Optional calls, you can call event function in that way func?.().

You need to do those checks because the data is coming asynchronously, so you can't get array[n] elem before array is downloaded.

If you have more questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I tried the new syntax within the `TrendCard` but it's still returning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

Comment: First of all, you need to correct your way of the work with data. Because you don't need to get the first element of the array in that way.

Try to add a special check for posts before the Trend card. I mean {posts.length && <TrendCard ... />}

Comment: And I forgot there one more step:
id={posts?.[0]?.id}* like that. You need continue this chain up to the end, because it will try to get id from undefined

Comment: If I comment out the code, uncomment it and then save, everything is displayed on the page as it should be. However when I refresh all is undefined again

Comment: changing the syntax to `id={posts?.[0]?.id}` made it work even on refresh! thank you so much